# $_GET not working on PHP mail activation

Tags: php

> localhost/blink/activate.php?email?=iamuser@localhost&activate_code=36486d71147a97037515616677c7359b

That is my activation link. However, PHP is not recognizing it.

```
if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['activate_code']) === true){

    echo 'Works!';
}
```

I'm not getting any output on the PHP page. I don't see the echo after I clicked the link. What is wrong the IF statement?

UPDATE: Here is how I assigned it.

```
email($regi_data['email'], 'Activate your account',"Hey "  .$regi_data['username']. ",\n\nYou need to activate your account.\n\nPlease click on the link below:\n http://localhost/blink/activate.php?email=". $regi_data['email'] . "&activate_code=" . $regi_data['activate_code'] . "\n\n-Blink");
```

Comment: aside from the question i recommend just sending an activation code, the email should already be stored

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `=` for assigning values to keys, not `?` and `==` as you did with `email`.

> localhost/blink/activate.php?email=iamuser@localhost&activate_code=36486d71147a97037515616677c7359b

You should probably also encode the parameters with `urlencode()`, which would make the `@` into `%40`.

Comment: How is that done? I have updated the post on how I assigned my email. Could you please change it for me?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra ? in your link after email. It should be:

localhost/blink/activate.php?email=iamuser@localhost&activate_code=36486d71147a97037515616677c7359b